# Delphi 2010 and Dbexpress deploy

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010, dbexpress

How on Earth to deploy a Delphi 2009 /2010 app that connects to a remote mysql using dbexpress? What files to include? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need dbexpress driver for MySQL (dbxmys.dll), and MySQL client library which is a single DLL (libmySQL.dll).

In Delphi 2009, there is a bug (I'm not sure if it is fixed by any update), which makes you deploy dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini files with your application too; otherwise you will get a runtime error on the target machine. There are a few workarounds for it like creating an in-memory connection manager in your code, which was mentioned in Marco Cantu's Delphi 2009 Handbook.

Comment: It was fixed in a service pack - see http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2008/09/delphi-2009-using-dbx4-framework.html